# How to add fontColor, fontBackgroundColor, fontSize to ckeditor5 in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import BalloonEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon";

class MyEditor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HEllo world</h2>
        <CKEditor
          config={{
            toolbar: {
              items: [
                  'heading', '|',
                  'alignment', '|',
                   'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                  'link', '|',
                  'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList',
                  '-', // break point
                  'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
                  'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
                  'insertTable', '|',
                  'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                  'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
                  'undo', 'redo'
              ],
              shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
          }
          }}
          editor={BalloonEditor}
          data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
          onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            console.log( { event, editor, data } );
        } }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

Nothing complex in the above code I am trying to get familiar with ckeditor5.
My question here is all the options in the items array above is visible in toolbar **except**

```
'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'
```

I know I am missing something here. I searched for the solution in the ckeditor5 docs but couldn't find the solution specially for React.

I appreciate your help so much. Thanks is advance.

Comment: You can use ClassicEditor class. Checkout this [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seem `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon` not support [Font plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html#configuring-the-font-family-feature).

You have to [Customize one of the existing builds](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html)

```
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';
...

class MyEditor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HEllo world</h2>
        <CKEditor
          config={{
            plugins: [ Font, ... ],
            toolbar: [ 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', ... ]
            ...
          }}
          // rest props
        } }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

or Create your own by using [CKEditor online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using create-react-app so i have less control on my webpack so i am continuing with existing builds. bt while importing the Font it is giving me this error :ckeditor-duplicated-modules.

Comment: link to my codesandbox where i have reproduce this error: https://codesandbox.io/s/playing-with-ckeeditor-5-66itv?file=/src/MyEditor.js

Comment: I suggest you should build your own to reduce the package size, unused plugins,...